# Elastic Beanstalk Node Nginx - Caching entire Angular 2 dist folder

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, caching, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am looking to optimize the caching/loading of my angular 2 app which is going to be running on Elastic Beanstalk with load balancing and multiple ec2 instances. I see that you can set specific folders to cache javascript, html and css using the nginx static setting on the elastic beanstalk console but for Angular 2 built apps everything sits in the dist folder in a couple bundles. How does one go about caching these using Elastic Beanstalk and Nginx?